# What do primed coordinates refer to in Griffith's section on Helmholtz Theorem?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology, conventions, vector-fields

In his section on Helmholtz theorem Griffith uses primed coordinates in the integrals that define $U$ and $\mathbf{W}$. Now, I understand that primed coordinates are used for sources (charges and currents), but in this context, where Griffith is talking about general vector fields (not necessarily electric and magnetic fields), what is the meaning of primed coordinates?

Comment: Its essentially the same. The current and the charge density are now understood as another vectorfield and scalarfield. The fact that they are primed is only notation.

Answer (score 0):

In general, they are dummy variables to integrate, but I would add that OP's intuition of primed variables referring to *sources* in the context of Helmholtz's theorem is also valid for general vector fields, because in analogy with the electrical and magnetic sources, for a general field $\mathbf{F}$ we can call ${\cal D(\mathbf{r})=\nabla\cdot\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})}$ its scalar sources and ${\cal C}(\mathbf{r})=\nabla\times\mathbf{F}$ its vector sources. With these names, the theorem becomes more mundane, it just says that given some not too-restrictive conditions we should be able to determine a field from its sources. So the bottom line is: when Griffiths defines $U$ and $\mathbf{W}$ as integrals over $\cal D$ and $\cal C$ he is definitely integrating over sources.